# Do we need a client to accept SFTP file transfers on the client system?

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, sharpssh

Please forgive if this is a basic question.

I'm working SFTP file transfer using c# (SharpSSH) and I just want to know whether we need to have a client on the other system to recieve the files.

Please suggest where I can get the relevent information.

Comment: You probably meant a server, didn't you?

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp : Yes, After reading for 2 days what SFTP is  ..

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need something on the receiving device, specifically software that is listening on the correct port for the SFTP protocol. You do not specify the target server but see https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows for Windows SSH servers.

See see https://serverfault.com/questions/50577/what-is-the-difference-between-sftp-port-22-or-port-990 and https://serverfault.com/questions/74176/what-port-does-sftp-use for more info on the ports used.